# Get localized display attribute in a controller using Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an enum type that is localized using DisplayAttribute, a resource file and aspnetcore built in localization support. I can successfully verify that the localization works in a view by for example using

```
Html.GetEnumSelectList<TypeExample>().
```

How can I get the same localized DisplayAttribute in a controller or even a Model.

I tried using code like:

```
var name = TypeExample.A.GetType()?
            .GetMember(TypeExample.A.ToString())?
            .FirstOrDefault()?
            .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.GetName();
```

but it does not return the localized display name.

I would like to use it in a model for an ApiController eg.

```
public class Model
{
    public TypeExample Type { get; set; }

    public string TypeDisplayValue => Type.GetDisplayValue()
}
```

Comment: You can use an attribute for this, I believe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463166/asp-net-mvc6-localizable-displayattribute

Comment: I am using DisplayAttribute. Will try some of the solutions there later. However, first try did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I succeeded with this task.

I created a enum translator service that is registered i startup as transient service

```
public class EnumTranslatorService:IEnumTranslatorService
{
    private IModelMetadataProvider _metadataProvider;

    public EnumTranslatorService(IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider)
    {
        _metadataProvider = metadataProvider;
    }

    public string TranslateDisplayName<TEnum>(TEnum e) where TEnum : struct
    {
        var a = _metadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(e.GetType());
        var name = a.EnumGroupedDisplayNamesAndValues.FirstOrDefault(t => 
                       t.Value ==  a.EnumNamesAndValues[e.ToString()]).Key.Name;

        return name ?? e.ToString();
    }
}
```

It uses IModelMetadataProvider that is created in aspnetcore. Once injected I use it as:

```
_enumTranslatorService.TranslateDisplayName(EnumExampleType.A)
```

Comment: This was the only approach which allowed me to display the localized enum display name using the ShraredLocalizer approach with the dummy class and single resx file for every language.